# Linphone iOS push notification and App ID

Tags: push-notification, linphone, apn

I'm wondering question about push notification for Linphone (installed from AppStore). I'm  not Apple Developer and not famous with APN details just trying to setup Flexisip proxy as frontend for Asterisk and everything works except PUSH.
I see that Linphone sends **pn-param=ABCD1234.org.linphone.phone.voip** so I assume that I need to get certificate associated with App ID **org.linphone.phone**
But the problem I cannot register this App ID on developer.apple.com  because it returns *"An App ID with Identifier 'org.linphone.phone' is not available"* error.
Is there any way to change pn-param sending by Linphone? Or I can use another App ID with Linphone?

Any advice appreciate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can't create an app with a package name that is already being used.
But you can't either use our push notifications as our certificate used by sip.linphone.org flexisip is private.

What you can do is build your own iOS app using another package name, and generate & install your own push certificates on your flexisip push gateway.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you. I have built my own version of Linphone and push is working now.